# WebStorm Debug Remote React Web App with SourceMaps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundle, webstorm, javascript-debugger

I have a deployed React web application and I'm looking to debug the remote app by stepping through the code.  The deployed application has sourcemaps.  How can I setup WebStorm's JavaScript debugger for the remote app?  Currently the breakpoints are not registering.

```
// Remote
https://myapp.com/js/bundle.js
https://myapp.com/js/bundle.js.map
```

```
// Local
src/components/component1.js
src/components/component2.js
```

Comment: Can you give us more details please ? Build with webpack ? Parcel ? How are generated source maps ? When ? etc.

Comment: The source maps are generated when building with webpack.

Answer (score 0):

To debug a JavaScript application in WebStorm you have to use the JavaScript Debug configuration. Add `https://myapp.com` to the URL field. As long as the deployed application has sourcemaps, the breakpoints should be hit.
However, in some cases you might need to configure some top-level mappings in the debug configuration as well (`Remote URL of local files` section in the JavaScript Debug configuration). For example, you might need to map the root of your local project with `https://myapp.com/js/`.

Comment: I have the `Remote URL of local files` configured, but the breakpoints aren't working.  When developing locally, in the Debug's window `Scripts` tab, `webpack://` shows up, but when trying to debug the remote application, `webpack://` does not show up in the `Scripts` tab.  Could this be the reason for the breakpoints not working?

Comment: please create a support ticket and share your idea.log (**Help > Show Log in...**) plus screenshots of your run configuration and *Scripts* tab